# How to make an element inherit a set of CSS rules for another element?

Tags: css

Say I have a `<div>` like this that is going to have all of the same properties with a background image or something like that:

```css
div.someBaseDiv {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And I wanted to inherit from it like this:

```css
div.someBaseDiv someInheritedDiv {
    background-image: url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 950px;
    height: 572px;
}
```

Of course I’m pretty sure this is written wrong, and I’m not afraid to ask for help, so can someone tell me how to make this work and include the HTML markup?

Comment: You may be confusing inhertiance with the "someInhertedDiv". As stated, not all properties are inherited, only some, such as color, font-size, font-weight etc. You may have HTML as "<div id="parent">I am a parent<div id="child">I am a child</div></div>" and CSS as "div#parent{color: blue;}", Now the div#child will also have color blue. That is CSS inheritance at work.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The easiest is to add your someInheritedDiv element to the first rule like this.

```css
div.someBaseDiv,
#someInheritedDiv
{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

This will tell your #someInheritedDiv to apply the same styles as div.someBaseDiv has. Then you *extend* this set of styles with more specific to your #someInheritedDiv:

```css
#someInheritedDiv
{
    background-image:url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:950px;
    height:572px;
}
```

This is how **specificity** in CSS works.

Answer (score 29):

Use both classes and combine them like so:

```
.baseClass
{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.baseClass.otherClass /* this means the element has both baseClass and otherClass */
{
    background-image:url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:950px;
    height:572px;
}
```

The markup is as follows:

```
<div class="baseClass otherClass"></div>
```

Now, in this fashion you can override baseClass if necessary... and since you don't have to keep adding your new class names to the baseClass definition, it's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 14):

For this task, I would recommend you use a powerful extension of CSS called [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It compiles into CSS or can be used on-the-fly with a javascript file as the link explains.

LESS supports inheritance (almost) as you describe. The [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#docs) has the details (see the section "Mixins").

For your example, the LESS code would be:

```
.someBaseDiv {
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

someInheritedDiv {
    .someBaseDiv;

    background-image:url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:950px;
    height:572px;
}
```

Note that it would have to be `.someBaseDiv` and not `div.someBaseDiv`

Comment: Just a note – LESS is not an extension of CSS at all. It's a pre-processor written in Javascript.

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do is make some CSS apply to two different types of elements, but allow them to have some differences as well. You can do this using some simple HTML:

```
<div class="base">
    <div class"inherited">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.base, .inherited{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.inherited{
    background-image:url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:950px;
    height:572px;
}
```

This will add the shared properties to both types of `div`, but specific ones only to derived `div`s

Answer (score 4):

That really depends on your markup. If your inherited element resides under a div with class `someBasDiv`, then all child elements of it will automatically inherit those properties.

If however, you want to inherit the `someBaseDiv` class in any place in your markup, you could just make the element which you want to inherit with, use both of those classes like this:

```
<div class="someBaseDiv someInheritedDiv">
```

and your css would be like this:

```
div.someBaseDiv
{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

div.someInheritedDiv
{
    background-image:url("images/worldsource/customBackground.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:950px;
    height:572px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the inner DIVs with a specific class to inherit from the base class build the HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">X</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.parent { border: 2px solid red; color: white }
.parent .child { background: black }
```

If all DIVs must inherit change `.child` to `div`.

[**See this example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yeraq/)

The following code

```
// parent     // all DIVs inside the parent
.someClass    div { }
```

Means: A top element (any) with the class `someClass` will add the styles to all its children DIVs (recursively).