# Text styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer in my HTML file:

```
<footer>
    <p>
        Copyright &copy; 2013.
    </p>
</footer>
```

And here is my css file:

```
footer {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

But why it didn't change my text style? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: you should go more specific. in means of CSS use "footer p or footer > p". Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377029/css-inheritance

Comment: strangely enough, I find this version of code itself to be working fine in IE, Chrome and FF. wondering what could be the reason :(

Comment: Yeah, works for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to print this:

```
footer {
    background: #333;
}

footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

instead of this:

```
footer {
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

In CSS you always need to cut your code on `p`, `h2` `a`, `span` etc.

Comment: Did this actually solve the problem? Then the real problem was not disclosed: there is apparently some CSS setting that sets properties on the `p` element. It is not true that “you always need to cut your code on `p`, `h2` `a`, `span` etc.” Here the `p` element would inherit color, font, background, and alignment setting, unless other style sheets prevent that.

Comment: but anyway Sergii Arhipov's footer now have a text style as he wanted