# CSS class templates?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to create a "template" class in CSS that can be used in multiple classes? For example:

```
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ededed;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.tileA {
    class: tile;
    height: 100px;
}

.tileB {
    class: tile;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: no, not in css anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this :

```
.tile, .tileA, .tileB {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ededed;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.tileA {
    height: 100px;
}

.tileB {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use classes efficiently. You can give multiple classes to elements.

You can use pre-processors like `LESS` and `SASS`.

Try:

HTML:

```
<element class="tile tileA"></element>
<element class="tile tileB"></element>
```

CSS:

```
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ededed;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.tileA {
    height: 100px;
}

.tileB {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out CSS pre-processors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). I know SASS does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit as such using CSS but as previously demonstrated you can assign the "sub-classes" to the base class definition See: [CSS Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377029/css-inheritance)

There is also quite a good article regarding CSS and inheritance targeted at Object Orientated programmers: http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/

There are third party tools which can do something similar ([SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) I believe is quite popular) but basically pure CSS does not support inheritence.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the classical programming sense, no. At least, not with vanilla CSS.

There are a couple ways to do something similar, though:

- Use multiple classes on the elements, eg `class="tile tileA"`
- Use a preprocessor (such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)) and use an [@extend directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend):

---

```
%tile { 
    ... 
 }
.tileA  {
   @extend %tile;
   height: 100px;
}
.tileB {
   @extend %tile;
   height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the markdown is breaking in my code- arg.

Answer (score 0):

it would be possible with [COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

That's what Sass for , try it

Answer (score 0):

### Attribute Selector Could Work Well Here

This would apply the css to all the `.tile` classes looking at the [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[class^='tile'], /* selects if any "tile" class is the first class */
[class*=' tile'] /* selects if any later class starting with "tile" */
{
    position: absolute;
    background: #ededed;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.tileA {
    height: 100px;
}

.tileB {
    height: 200px;
}
```